Filter Data Based on Time
How can i filter the data based on time. using oracle database, asp.net web form and query. oracle database outtime column datatype is date. Pls help
HTML
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="card">

          <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="form-group m-0">
                          <label for="OrgList">Select a Floor</label>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="FloorList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control select2" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.form-group -->
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="form-group m-0">
                          <label for="OrgList">Select a Section</label>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="SectionList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control select2" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.form-group -->
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      <label>Search by date range:</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <span class="input-group-text">
                                  <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                              </span>
                          </div>
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="daterange" CssClass="form-control float-right" />
                          <span class="input-group-append">
                              <asp:Button runat="server" ID="attnFilter" Text="Run" OnClick="attendance_summary_report_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-flat" />
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.input group -->
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Main row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="card">
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="Attn_RV" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.card -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>

jQuery
window.onload = function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#OrgList, #FloorList, #SectionList').select2({
      theme: 'bootstrap4'
    });
  })
}

//=== end function
let date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Date range picker
  $('#daterange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: firstDay,
    endDate: lastDay,
    ranges: {
      'Current Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    locale: {
      format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY'
    }
  });

});

Asp
    string date = (daterange.Text == "") ? DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : daterange.Text;
    string[] datearr = date.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string from = datearr[0].Trim();
    string to = datearr[1].Trim();
    //ReportProduct(from, to, orgid);
  }
}

private void DropFloorData() {
  string orgid = Session["ORGID"].ToString();
  var item = OracleDbQuery.GetCompanies().Find(o => o.Companyid == orgid);

  using(OracleConnection con = DbConn.GetConnection(item.Companyid)) {
    string query = "select floor_id, floor_desc from floor order by floor_desc";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    con.Open();
    OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows) {
      FloorList.Items.Clear();
      FloorList.DataSource = rdr;
      FloorList.DataValueField = "floor_desc";
      FloorList.DataTextField = "floor_desc";
      FloorList.DataBind();

      FloorList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Floor", "%"));
    } else {
      FloorList.DataSource = null;
      FloorList.DataBind();
      FloorList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Floor", "%"));
    }
  }
}

private void DropSectionData() {
  string orgid = Session["ORGID"].ToString();
  var item = OracleDbQuery.GetCompanies().Find(o => o.Companyid == orgid);

  using(OracleConnection con = DbConn.GetConnection(item.Companyid)) {
    string query = "select section_no, section_name from section order by section_name";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    con.Open();
    OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows) {
      SectionList.Items.Clear();
      SectionList.DataSource = rdr;
      SectionList.DataValueField = "section_name";
      SectionList.DataTextField = "section_name";
      SectionList.DataBind();
      SectionList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Section", "%"));
    } else {
      SectionList.DataSource = null;
      SectionList.DataBind();
      SectionList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Section", "%"));
    }
  }
}

protected void attendance_summary_report_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string date = (daterange.Text == "") ? DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : daterange.Text;
  string[] datearr = date.Split(new [] {
    " - "
  }, StringSplitOptions.None);
  string from = datearr[0].Trim();
  string to = datearr[1].Trim();
  string section = SectionList.SelectedItem.Value;
  string floor = FloorList.SelectedItem.Value;
  string orgid = Session["ORGID"].ToString();
  ReportProduct(section, floor, from, to, orgid);
}

public void ReportProduct(string section, string floor, string from, string to, string orgid) {
  Attendance_ds timecard_dt = GetData(section, floor, from, to, orgid);
  Attn_RV.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
  Attn_RV.SizeToReportContent = true;
  Attn_RV.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

  Attn_RV.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
  Attn_RV.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
  Attn_RV.ZoomPercent = 100;
  Attn_RV.ShowZoomControl = true;
  Attn_RV.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;

  foreach(RenderingExtension extension in Attn_RV.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions()) {
    if (extension.Name == "IMAGE" || extension.Name == "WORD") {
      FieldInfo fi = extension.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      fi.SetValue(extension, false);
    }
  }

  Attn_RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
  Attn_RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("AttendanceDataSet", timecard_dt.Tables[2]));
  Attn_RV.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/reports/attn_reports/attn_summary_individual.rdlc");
}

private Attendance_ds GetData(string section, string floor, string from, string to, string orgid) {
  CompanyInfo company = OracleDbQuery.GetCompanies().Find(o => o.Companyid == orgid);
  using(OracleConnection con = DbConn.GetConnection(company.Companyid)) {
    string query = OracleDbQuery.GetMonthlyAttendanceSummary(floor, section, from, to, company.Company_name);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    con.Open();
    OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(attn_ds, attn_ds.AttendanceSumIndv.ToString());
  }
  return attn_ds;

}
}

}

Oracle Query:
    WITH
    CTE_EmployeeSearchByTime AS(
        SELECTTO_CHAR(ad.att_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS ATTDATE,
        eo.company_name AS COMPANY,
        eo.floor_desc AS FLOOR,
        eo.section_name AS SECTION,
        eo.line_info AS LINE,
        ep.empno AS EMPNO,
        ep.first_name AS NAME,
        eo.des_name AS DESIGNATION,
        TO_CHAR(ad.in_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS INTIME,
        TO_CHAR(ad.out_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS OUTTIME,
        ad.othour AS OTFROMemp_personal epLEFT
    JOIN emp_official eo ON
        ep.empno = eo.empnoLEFT
    JOIN attendance_details ad ON
        ep.empno = ad.empnoWHERETO_CHAR(ad.att_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') = '{todate}' AND ad.status LIKE 'P' AND TO_CHAR(ad.out_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '{starttime}' AND '{endtime}' AND eo.company_name = '{company}'
    )
SELECT
    * FROMCTE_EmployeeSearchByTimeORDER BYFLOOR,
    LINE,
    SECTION,
    TO_NUMBER(EMPNO) ASC

I want to try solve this issue. Please help. Thanks advance

Please click [edit], then the [<>] snippet editor and make a [mcve] using rendered HTML and script. It is not clear if you have issues with the JavaScript, the asp or the oracle query.

Please remove window.onload = function () { } since $(function () { }) does the same.

Your asp code is incomplete.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: an English explanation of the precise part of the code that is causing issues; and the relevant code for that part of the problem - if the issue is with the client selecting the dates then include the JavaScript and the HTML; if the issue is passing the dates to the database then include the ASP code; if the issue is retrieving the correct rows from the database then include the Oracle code; but do not include lots of unnecessary code that is irrelevant to the problem and do not include everything and leave us to guess what the problem is.

Without some sample data and the expected result it's hard to tell what you realy want. Here is a blind guess of sample data and a query which results with the dataset you could use for different reportings ...
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    emp_personal ( EMPNO, FIRST_NAME ) AS
      ( Select  1, 'John' From Dual Union All
        Select  2, 'Jane' From Dual Union All
        Select  3, 'Kate' From Dual Union All
        Select  4, 'Mike' From Dual Union All
        Select  5, 'Anne' From Dual 
      ),
    emp_official ( ID, EMPNO, COMPANY_NAME, FLOOR_DESC, SECTION_NAME, LINE_INFO ) AS
      ( Select 101, 1, 'Company A', 'Floor desc A 1', 'Section A 1 S1', 'Line A 1 S1 L1' From Dual Union All 
        Select 102, 2, 'Company A', 'Floor desc A 1', 'Section A 1 S2', 'Line A 1 S2 L1' From Dual Union All 
        Select 103, 3, 'Company A', 'Floor desc A 2', 'Section A 1 S2', 'Line A 1 S2 L2' From Dual Union All 
        Select 104, 4, 'Company B', 'Floor desc B 2', 'Section B 2 S4', 'Line B 2 S4 L0' From Dual Union All 
        Select 105, 5, 'Company B', 'Floor desc B 5', 'Section B 5 S1', 'Line B 5 S1 L9' From Dual 
      ),
    attendance_details ( ID, ATT_DATE, EMPNO, IN_TIME, OUT_TIME ) AS 
      ( Select  1001, To_Date('13.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1, To_Date('13.06.2024 08:57:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('13.06.2024 17:03:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1002, To_Date('13.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 2, Null,                                                     To_Date('13.06.2024 16:59:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1003, To_Date('13.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 3, To_Date('13.06.2024 09:03:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('13.06.2024 16:50:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1004, To_Date('13.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, To_Date('13.06.2024 08:57:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('13.06.2024 17:05:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1005, To_Date('13.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 5, To_Date('13.06.2024 08:54:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('13.06.2024 16:43:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        --
        Select  1006, To_Date('14.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1, To_Date('14.06.2024 08:51:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('14.06.2024 17:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1007, To_Date('14.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 3, To_Date('14.06.2024 08:52:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('14.06.2024 17:01:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1008, To_Date('14.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 5, To_Date('14.06.2024 08:53:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('14.06.2024 17:01:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        --
        Select  1009, To_Date('15.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1, To_Date('15.06.2024 09:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('15.06.2024 17:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1010, To_Date('15.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 2, To_Date('15.06.2024 08:33:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('15.06.2024 17:01:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1011, To_Date('15.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 4, To_Date('15.06.2024 09:01:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('15.06.2024 17:02:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        Select  1012, To_Date('15.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 5, To_Date('15.06.2024 09:31:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('15.06.2024 17:03:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All 
        --
        Select  1013, To_Date('16.06.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1, To_Date('16.06.2024 08:55:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),  To_Date('16.06.2024 17:07:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') From Dual 
      ),

... if you need daily records about employee's presence create a cte that will generate dates for a period of interest
  dates_times AS 
    ( Select DISTINCT Min(ATT_DATE) Over() + LEVEL - 1 AS ATT_DATE, 
                      Min(ATT_DATE) Over() + LEVEL - 1 + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND AS START_DATE_TIME, 
                      Min(ATT_DATE) Over() + LEVEL - 1 + INTERVAL '17:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND AS END_DATE_TIME
      From attendance_details
      Connect By LEVEL - 1 <= ( Select Max(ATT_DATE) - Min(ATT_DATE) From attendance_details )
    ), 

... and collect all the employee's data for the period (another cte)
  employees_data AS
    ( SELECT    d.ATT_DATE,  
                --
                ep.EMPNO AS EMPNO, ep.FIRST_NAME AS NAME,
                To_Char(ad.IN_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS INTIME, TO_CHAR(ad.OUT_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS OUTTIME,
                --
                Case When ad.IN_TIME Is Null And ad.OUT_TIME Is Null
                     Then 'Not present'
                     When ad.IN_TIME Is Null And ad.OUT_TIME Is Not Null
                     Then 'Check out without check in'
                     When ad.IN_TIME Is Not Null And ad.OUT_TIME Is Null
                     Then 'Check in without check out'
                     When ad.IN_TIME > d.START_DATE_TIME And ad.OUT_TIME < d.END_DATE_TIME
                     Then 'Came late / Left early'
                     When ad.IN_TIME > d.START_DATE_TIME 
                     Then 'Came late'
                     When ad.OUT_TIME < d.END_DATE_TIME
                     Then 'Left early'
                End AS ISSUE,
                --
                eo.COMPANY_NAME AS COMPANY, eo.FLOOR_DESC AS FLOOR,
                eo.SECTION_NAME AS SECTION, eo.LINE_INFO AS LINE
      FROM        emp_personal ep
      INNER JOIN emp_official eo ON( ep.EMPNO = eo.EMPNO )
      INNER JOIN dates_times d ON( 1 = 1 )
      LEFT JOIN attendance_details ad ON( ep.EMPNO = ad.EMPNO And ad.ATT_DATE = d.ATT_DATE )
    )

--    M a i n    S Q L :
--  here you could define different selections/conditions/aggregations/groupings ...
SELECT      * 
FROM        employees_data 
ORDER BY    ATT_DATE, EMPNO

/*        R e s u l t :
ATT_DATE      EMPNO NAME INTIME   OUTTIME  ISSUE                      COMPANY   FLOOR          SECTION        LINE          
-------- ---------- ---- -------- -------- -------------------------- --------- -------------- -------------- --------------
13.06.24          1 John 08:57:00 17:03:00                            Company A Floor desc A 1 Section A 1 S1 Line A 1 S1 L1
13.06.24          2 Jane          16:59:00 Check out without check in Company A Floor desc A 1 Section A 1 S2 Line A 1 S2 L1
13.06.24          3 Kate 09:03:00 16:50:00 Came late / Left early     Company A Floor desc A 2 Section A 1 S2 Line A 1 S2 L2
13.06.24          4 Mike 08:57:00 17:05:00                            Company B Floor desc B 2 Section B 2 S4 Line B 2 S4 L0
13.06.24          5 Anne 08:54:00 16:43:00 Left early                 Company B Floor desc B 5 Section B 5 S1 Line B 5 S1 L9
--
14.06.24          1 John 08:51:00 17:00:00                            Company A Floor desc A 1 Section A 1 S1 Line A 1 S1 L1
14.06.24          2 Jane                   Not present                Company A Floor desc A 1 Section A 1 S2 Line A 1 S2 L1
14.06.24          3 Kate 08:52:00 17:01:00                            Company A Floor desc A 2 Section A 1 S2 Line A 1 S2 L2
14.06.24          4 Mike                   Not present                Company B Floor desc B 2 Section B 2 S4 Line B 2 S4 L0
14.06.24          5 Anne 08:53:00 17:01:00                            Company B Floor desc B 5 Section B 5 S1 Line B 5 S1 L9
--
15.06.24          1 John 09:00:00 17:00:00                            Company A Floor desc A 1 Section A 1 S1 Line A 1 S1 L1
15.06.24          2 Jane 08:33:00 17:01:00                            Company A Floor desc A 1 Section A 1 S2 Line A 1 S2 L1
15.06.24          3 Kate                   Not present                Company A Floor desc A 2 Section A 1 S2 Line A 1 S2 L2
15.06.24          4 Mike 09:01:00 17:02:00 Came late                  Company B Floor desc B 2 Section B 2 S4 Line B 2 S4 L0
15.06.24          5 Anne 09:31:00 17:03:00 Came late                  Company B Floor desc B 5 Section B 5 S1 Line B 5 S1 L9
--
16.06.24          1 John 08:55:00 17:07:00                            Company A Floor desc A 1 Section A 1 S1 Line A 1 S1 L1
16.06.24          2 Jane                   Not present                Company A Floor desc A 1 Section A 1 S2 Line A 1 S2 L1
16.06.24          3 Kate                   Not present                Company A Floor desc A 2 Section A 1 S2 Line A 1 S2 L2
16.06.24          4 Mike                   Not present                Company B Floor desc B 2 Section B 2 S4 Line B 2 S4 L0
16.06.24          5 Anne                   Not present                Company B Floor desc B 5 Section B 5 S1 Line B 5 S1 L9  */

NOTE:
Oracle DATE datatype always contains time component (00:00:00 if not defined like ATT_DATE column in attendance_details cte). You can add/subtract different INTERVAL(s) to a DATE column like  START_DATE_TIME/END_DATE_TIME columns in dates_times cte.

DATE FACTORY FLOOR SECTION LINE CODE NAME DESIGNATION INTIME OUTTIME OT
1/6/2024 MOHARA ASIAN APPARELS LTD. FLOOR-01 QUALITY LINE-01 7697 SONIYA AKTER SEW. Q.I 7:58:44 15:59:44 0
1/6/2024 MOHARA ASIAN APPARELS LTD. FLOOR-01 QUALITY LINE-01 7771 MD. ANOWAR HOSSEN SEW. Q.I 7:58:59 15:59:44 0
1/6/2024 MOHARA ASIAN APPARELS LTD. FLOOR-01 QUALITY LINE-01 390129 JENIFA NASRIN AKHI SEW. Q.I 8:06:18 15:59:44 0
1/6/2024 MOHARA ASIAN APPARELS LTD. FLOOR-01 SEWING HELPER LINE-01 5054 REHANA AKTER A. S. M. OPERATOR 7:58:15 15:59:44 0
